# Declaration inside a loop

Tags: c++, c++14

In for loop like below

```cpp
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
  vector<int>v(100);
}
```

In this i have a doubt that

1. for each loop will the vector will be declare again and again? If yes why it do not causes problem(because if we redeclare same thing it cause problem like two time int x;).
2. do the size keep on increasing on each loop till the end, in above or for such loop

```cpp
for(int i=0;i<10000;i++) {
 int k;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> for each loop will the vector will be declared again and again?

For each loop, the vector will be declared again. Each time control passes through its definition, it will be newly initialized, and each time an iteration of the loop ends, **it will be destroyed**. Therefore, it does not cause a redeclaration issue. Each time the vector is created, it will be in the same size.

> do the size keep on increasing on each loop till the end, in above or for such loop

I'm not sure what you meant by that. The loop will run  until the `for` condition is met (i.e `i<10000`) and each time `k` will be newly initialized and then destroyed.

Answer (score 4):

> for each loop will the vector will be declare again and again?

No.

There is only declaration but the object is constructed in each iteration of the loop and destructed in each iteration of the loop.

The following is illegal because there are two declaration of the variable.

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   vector<int> v(100);
   vector<int> v;
}
```

> do the size keep on increasing on each loop till the end, in above or for such loop

It's not clear what you mean by that. Whose *size* are you talking about?

The size of the code generated by the compiler? That does not change.

The size of memory used by the computer at run time? That does not change either.

Does it take longer to run? Yes.